# Typescript Namespace and Bundling

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces, webpack

I am using typescript defined react controls/actions like below in different namespaces.

AX.ts

```
namespace A {
 export class X {
   doX() {
   }
 }
}
```

AY.ts

```
///<reference path="AX.ts"/>
namespace A {
 export class Y {
  doY() {
     //Call A.X.doX
  }
 }
}
```

Webpack (webpack.config.js) is configured with:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "src/AY.ts",
  output: {
      filename: "dist/axy.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

Output of webpack in axy.js only has transpiled javascript code of AY.ts and not AX.ts

I see from ts documentation that modules defined in multiple ts files cannot be merged in single js, however am assuming this doesn't apply for namespace.